# Mavericks lock screen doesn't show screen saver

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

Prior to upgrading to Mavericks, when I chose to lock my MacBook Pro's screen, it would do so with my screen saver options (rotate through images in a folder, and show a clock). However, when I go to lock my screen now, it's simply a black screen.

Is there a way to make Mavericks use my screen saver settings when I choose to lock my screen as with older versions of OS X?

Comment: How to do usually lock your screen ?

Comment: @AntoineLecaille I have the lock icon in my menu bar up top.

Comment: @AntoineLecaille: If you go to Keychain Access->Preferences, and check "Show keychain status in menu bar", then a lock menu will appear allowing you to lock the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Check system preference -> Security & Privacy -> General-> Require password XXX after sleep or screen saver begins

Comment: That was the first thing I checked, and the box is checked. I have it set for immediately on the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

Set one of the hot corners to start the screen safer. 
The lock sends the display to sleep in mavericks - there's no option to change it afaik

Comment: But if it doesn't lock the screen, then anyone can walk up to my machine and use it, so this isn't a solution.

Comment: Go to security in system preferences. There you can set the amount of minutes (or immediately) until a password is requested after activating screen saver.